# Absolute Galois group, number theory and the Axiom of Choice

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-theory, axiom-of-choice, absolute-galois-group

Richard Taylor once explained his research (in number theory) in a very simple way: understanding the absolute Galois group $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$.

It is known that in Zermelo-Fraenkel theory without the Axiom of Choice, it is consistent to say that $\vert \mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q}) \vert = 2$.

What are the consquences for number theory in such a model ?

Comment: Why would you need the axiom of choice to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7},\zeta_3)$ is a Galois extension of degree larger than $2$?

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich Is there a way to lift those automorphisms to $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ without AC? The usual argument uses Zorn's Lemma.

Comment: @ArielWeiss In the absence of AC you have to be careful what you mean by the symbol $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ since one cannot prove the uniqueness of the algebraic closure. If you are referring to the usual algebraic closure, then you don't need Zorn's lemma because you can use the natural ordering on $\mathbb{N}$ to list all polynomials with integer coefficients in a canonical way.

Comment: I have a general problem with these kind of questions about foundations as they apply to mainstream math. If e.g. ZFC were for some obscure reason found to be inconsistent, then every statement would follow from it. But the idea that that would render the math people have done for hundreds (or thousands) of years meaningless is silly...

Comment: AC has no relevant consequence on arithmetic. In fact, defining things carefully it can even be a theorem that arithmetical statement are independant of AC. When people say they want to understand the absolue Galois group, what they mean is that they want to understand the category of finite extention of $\mathbb{Q}$. If you assume AC, then that's indeed the same as understanding the absolute Galois group, but if you don't the absolute Galois group is no longer relevant. We can rephrase most of what we know about it in terms of finite extension and make these independent of AC.

Comment: @SamHopkins There is a more charitable reading of the question, which is that it asks if there exists an interesting exotic object that is similar to a known object but that has been undeservedly neglected. In the case at hand, I think the answer is no (if we define "interesting" as "number-theoretically interesting"), but I don't see anything wrong with asking the question.

Answer (score 24):

In the absence of the axiom of choice, it is still possible to define the "usual" algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ because you can just explicitly enumerate all polynomials with integer coefficients.  Richard Taylor's remark should be interpreted as referring to this particular algebraic closure.

What you can't prove without choice is the *uniqueness* of the algebraic closure. Exotic algebraic closures could exist. So in the absence of choice, it's a bit misleading to use the notation $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ as if it referred to some unique thing. Wilfrid Hodges, in his paper, [Läuchli's algebraic closure of $Q$](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100052282), shows that an exotic algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ can have all kinds of unexpected properties.  But what this shows, in my opinion, is that what we usually think of as "algebraic number theory" doesn't make too much sense in that context.  When people talk about "algebraic number theory" they are tacitly referring to the usual algebraic closure.

Comment: I think it is more correct to say that when people talk about "algebraic number theory" they only talk about finite extention of $\mathbb{Q}$. The "usual" algebraic closure can have very few automorphisms.

Comment: @SimonHenry Is it that the usual algebraic closure can have few automorphisms? Specifically, using $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ for the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{C}$, is it possible that there is a Galois extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$ for which $\text{Aut}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q}) \to \text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ is not surjective? I used to think this could happen, but Timothy Chow's comment on the original question suggests not, and now I think I can prove that it can't happen.

Comment: @SimonHenry Every automorphism of a finite extension of $\mathbb Q$ lifts to an automorphism of the “usual” algebraic closure, as the latter is countable.

Comment: Interesting. So there is only one countable algebraic closure. Thanks !

Comment: I'm a bit confused, how can one prove that the algebraic closure is countable ? The "order the polynomials canonically" only seems to give that the algebraic closure is a countable union of finite sets. Must that be countable without AC ? (once you have a well-order on $\overline {\mathbb Q}$ clearly there is no issue)

Comment: Ah nevermind, I am silly: you can order the roots, say lexicographically in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi A countable union of finite sets is not necessarily countable without AC, but as you're enumerating the polynomials, you can discard any roots that you have encountered already.

Comment: @Timothy Chow : sure but you still need to order the ones you've added and that you have left. For this you can use the lexicographic order in $\mathbb C$

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Oh, I see now what you were concerned about. I'm slightly worried that if you try to rely on $\mathbb{C}$ then you run into subtleties about how to pick your embedding into $\mathbb{C}$. The way I would go about it is, when handed an irreducible polynomial such as $x^3 - 2$, to construct the splitting field directly from the polynomial, as outlined for example on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_field#Properties) (which, by the way, does caution about circular reasoning when proving the existence of an algebraic closure).

Comment: @TimothyChow : I'm a but confused as to how this allows you to enumerate all roots - a priori when you do this you add one root per polynomial. What the lexicographic order argument tells you is that the subfield of $\mathbb C$ of algebraic elements is countable - nothing about other ones or different embeddings

Comment: @MaximeRamzi First of all, I don't think you can add just one root per polynomial, can you? Given $x^3 - 2$, don't you want to adjoin *all* the roots? If you adjoin just one of them then you don't get the others, so when are the other roots going to get adjoined if not now? Secondly, the argument I have in mind does not begin by first constructing $\mathbb{C}$ somehow and then picking out a subfield. We start with $\mathbb{Q}$ and we build larger and larger extensions and take the union.

Comment: @TimothyChow : Yes I absolutely agree with the beginning of your comment, which is why I don't understand how your construction allows you to do this and guarantee countability. Let's say you have a polynomial $P$, and you add one root. In your new field, $P$ has some new irreducible factors (which are no longer part of your ordering of polynomials) : which one do you now choose ?

Comment: Ok I think I get it : at every stage, you have canonical orderings. You can choose, once and for all, a recipe that, given a bijection of your field $K$ with $\mathbb N$, produces a bijection of $K[X]$ with $\mathbb N$, and given a polynomial $P$, one of $K[X]/(P)$. So you order the polynomials of $\mathbb Q$ once and for all, and when you add roots to, say, $P$, you add them in the following way : $K$ has been created at a given stage so by induction I have an explicit bijection with $\mathbb N$, so I can order the irreducible factors of $P$ in $K$, and for each irreducible factor I can add

Comment: a first root, then do the same procedure in the new field to figure out which new irreducible factor I should split and so on. For any polynomial $P$, I only need to do this at most $deg(P)$ times so this terminates and I can move on to the next one, *and* I still have a chosen ordering of $K$. I think this works

Comment: And because any two countable algebraic closures are isomorphic, this method produces an algebraic closure which is isomorphic to the one obtained by "picking a subfield of $\mathbb C$" !

Answer (score 17):

There would be no consequences, for two reasons:

1. As Timothy Chow points out, if we define $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ as the set of complex numbers that are roots of a nonzero polynomial with rational coefficients, it is easy to prove the Galois group maps surjectively to the automorphism group of each finite Galois extension of $\mathbb Q$.
2. If we wanted to consider the Galois group of another field where there there really are set-theoretic issues with finding enough automorphisms (e.g. studying the automorphism group of $\mathbb C$) we could simply redefine our notion of "group" so it doesn't necessarily have a set of elements (e.g. as a group object in the category of locales) and there would be no difficulty with redoing the standard arguments in this setting.

Comment: On the other hand, we could say that number theory is about studying the absolute Galois group*oid* of $\mathbb{Q}$, and the statement that there is more than one algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ means its absolute Galois groupoid is not connected, which seems like its number-theoretically meaningful. I think it makes sense to ask more about these other, nonstandard, components, and I'm not convinced there's no interesting number-theoretic question there.

Comment: (This reminds me of the question of whether we can define right-derived functors for $M \mapsto M^I$ (where $I$ is a set and $M$ a module or even a vector space) in ZF, and, if so, what they look like. I can't decide whether it's a dumb question.)